# iptables: how to delete postrouting rule?

Tags: iptables

I would like to delete POSTROUTING rule below,

```
[root@hostname ~]# service iptables status
Table: nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

then I typed below,

```
[root@hostname ~]# iptables -D POSTROUTING 1
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try adding the table name explicitly:

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1
```

Comment: "is necessary" -- did you mean "is not necessary" ? Or did this fix your problem?

Comment: Sorry,I typed wrong. this fixed my problem thanks to your advice! Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent! [Don't forget to accept this as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that it can help others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Oh finally I found what I was looking for so long, thanks so much for your answer! Was messing around with my iptables configuration for hours and I always missed the -t nat part when trying to remove a very buggy rule. God bless you! +++

Comment: This didn't work for myself Ubuntu 13.04 (maybe from my own doings) but ```iptables -t nat -F``` did

Comment: @davidcollom, thanks, I marked your comment up with the hopes it'll be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: `service iptables status` doesn't show `nat` in its output. Is it possible to print it out?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp - `iptables -t nat -L` should show you the nat table